Difference between "REPL-Checkup" vs. "REPL-Distribution" (for the "Category" inside Job Activity Monitor)
I am working on creating Replication inside SQL 2022.
I created Replication subscription/subscriber for two different pipelines.
I noticed that, under Category inside Job Activity Monitor, for one subscription, it is indicated as "REPL-Distribution" (most of time), but for other one it is indicated as "REPL-Checkup".
There was no difference as far as how I created both subscriptions.
Why do I have different categories?
